# how to send json string and not url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<form id="msform" action="AN HTTP to AGENT" method="post">
```

If I post these form it sends json to a service:

```
$("#msform").submit(function(){


 // construct an HTTP request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

  // send the collected data as JSON
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify($('#msform').serializeObject()));

  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // done
  };

});
```

But in my database I get to see this info:

```
customerName=a&email=asd%40asd.com&phoneNumber=a&orderReference=a&item1=&amount1=&item2=&amount2=&item3
```

and I eventually want to save this it like this:

```
{"customerName":"asd@asd.com","email":"asd@asd.com",
  "phoneNumber":"asd@asd.com","orderReference":"
```

my questions are:

1. how do I do this ?
2. what will the difference be?

Comment: Is this your actual url? `action="AN HTTP to AGENT"`

Comment: no its a real http but i want to keep it private

Answer (score 0):

can you use a wrapper object to put all your data? So we can url encode the date before sending, then no data loss

```
data = $('#msform').serializeObject();
var res = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(data));   
var wrapper = new Object();
wrapper.content = res;
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(wrapper));
```

on server side: 
1) grab your data in wrapper as GET variable.
2) decode the url
3) now you have the JSON data

Comment: i now have done:  <form id="msform" action="the http of the agent" method="get">
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  
  data = $('#msform').serializeObject();
var res = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(data));   
xhr.send({ wrapper: res });

  // send the collected data as JSON
  //xhr.send(JSON.stringify($('#msform').serializeObject()));

  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // done
  };

Comment: and now i get: Error 400

HTTP Web Server: Unknown Command Exception

Comment: i have changed the code, plz check and see what u get instead of these customerName=a&email=asd%40asd.com&phoneNumber=a&orderReference=a&item1=&amount1=&item2=&amount2=&item3.  it should be data=<some scrambled url encoded data>

Comment: but why i need to use get, cant post suffice

Comment: because this is a get url customerName=a&email=asd%40asd.com&phoneNumber=a&orderReference=a&item1=&amount1=&item2=&amount2=&item3 values here are seperated using & and its a single string. This is what you get in server right? Also please check this https://jsfiddle.net/5dctggbd/

Comment: i think it has to do with because i am on localhost and try to post to another domain, because i also get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score 0):

This is the offending line or rather the cause of your misunderstanding

```
  // send the collected data as JSON
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify($('#msform').serializeObject()));
```

when you serialize a form in jquery you are turning the containing input fields into get query parameters and this is what you are sending to your database. To turn this into a jSON object that you can use in your Ajax call, you could simply  do something that looks like this.

```
var data = $('#msForm').serialize();
function objectify(data){
   var finalObj = {}
   var result = data.split('&').map(function(stringObj){
      var objectForm = {};
      var pair = stringObj.split("=");
      objectForm[pair[0]] = pair[1];
      return objectForm
   })
   result.forEach(function(obj){
       for(var prop in obj){
          finalObj[prop] = obj[prop]
       }
   })
   return finalObj
}
```

then just JSON.stringify the result returned by calling "objectify". But i'm sure there are libraries out there to do this nicely. I'm not a huje jquery person.

hope that helps

Comment: sorry i already have a function:
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};